# opening URL from a file and taking screenshots in UiPath

Tags: ui-automation, webpage-screenshot, rpa, uipath

It's a UI path sequence.

I am trying to read some URLs from an Excel file.

Launch browser
Go to URL from file
Take Screenshot
Save screenshot

I am unable to use the "take Screenshot" activity. Unsure, how can I take the screenshot and save it as a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Take Screenshot` activity requires a variable (of type `Image`). Select the activity first, and in the properties, click on Output. Then, hit CTRL+K to add a new variable (or enter an existing one).

Use the `Save Image`activity to save any variable of type `Image`to disk.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot boss. That worked. Could I make it read the URLs from an Excel file. Seems like Excel activities are not available in Community edition.

Comment: Excel activities need to be installed first via the package manager: https://forum.uipath.com/t/how-to-install-the-excel-activities-package/11967

Comment: Spot on! thanks. Now playing with something else and stuck. take a look on that new question if you have time.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51461100/looping-on-urls-from-excel-file-using-uipath?noredirect=1