# Looping on URLs from Excel file using UiPath

Tags: excel, automation, automated-tests, rpa, uipath

I have tried several ways but somehow they dont look clean;

1. I have a URL file in Excel format (400+ urls in a column)
2. I want UiPath to read from that file and browse these URLs one by one

I tried with making "Navigate to" read from a variable that reads from Excel but it just gets messy and does not work.

anyone can suggest some easy way to do it?

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Please elaborate. What works, and what does not? What is the actual and the expected behavior? What have you tried? Do you just intend to open (i.e. fire a GET request) to the URL, or do you need to manipulate or scrape anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please elaborate what you want to do.

As per my understanding, you have a Excel file with a column containing the URLs and you want to visit each one - in this case:

1. Take one excel application scope activity Give the path of your
   excel file...Create one DataTable object.
2. Use a `For Each Row` activity, providing your DataTable object.
3. Within the loop, use an `Assign` activity, and set `url=row.Item("urlColumnname").ToString()`
4. Use an `Navigate To` activiy to visit each URL.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your "Navigate to" activity is surrounded with an "Open Browser" or "Attach Browser" activity.

Additional tips will be:

- Use IE, while chrome and firefox plugins are available IE is natively
  supported.
- Consider adding a "delay" activity after each "Navigate",    this is
  specially when your network is slow or you have low latency causing the robot  to go faster than the browser itself and therefore, causing problems reading your selectors.