# UIPath - Iterating through excel file to fill in DataTable with Read Range "dynamically"

Tags: excel, uipath

my question is in principle the same target as [Looping on URLs from Excel file using UiPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51461100/looping-on-urls-from-excel-file-using-uipath)
(in the sense of reading in an Excel File with ReadRange an Iterating through it)

I want to iterate through the excel file - and would of course do this with an Excel Application Scope..
But when I read in a Excel File into a DataTable - I need to give this a range like "D2:K30"..

The "K30" would be the end of my range read in - so how do I manage to get the "end" of my specific excel file?

With VBA I would just iterate through the excel file and say something like

*'if row content is ""'*

, and then i would know when the first EMPTY row appears.

Maybe my first found empty row would be saved in Variable "emptyRow" - then I could say

*Read Range "D2:K" + emptyRow - 1*

So my target is to make this Read Range 'dynamically' in the sense of not copying empty rows into the datatable..

Because furthermore - when I copy that datatable into another excel file - I want to color specific ranges with different colors, therefore I need the specific length of each range, otherwise I will get empty rows colored as well..

Regards, Franz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this:

## Naïve approach

A very simple approach is to read a range just large enough - for example `A1:C10000`, and then loop over said range in order to find the first empty cell - at which point you would exit your loop. There's an obvious downside - this is not very efficient at all.

## Invoke VBA

Another option is to use the [Invoke VBA](https://activities.uipath.com/docs/invoke-vba) activity, and then use something like this:

```vb
Function GetRowCount()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim k As Long
    k = sh.Range("A1", sh.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    GetRowCount = k
End function
```

This should work just fine, but it requires you to use an Excel scope (and this requires you to have Excel installed).

## Combine Get Table and Get Range

This is probably my favorite one as you can simply use Workbook activities (i.e. without having Excel installed). However, it requires you to have your data in Excel [represented as a table](https://www.contextures.com/xlExcelTable01.html). Here's an example - the [Get Table Range](https://activities.uipath.com/docs/get-table-range) activity returns a range (as string, e.g. "A1:C42" which is then used in the [Read Range](https://activities.uipath.com/docs/read-range) activity.

[image: getTableRange]